# pandas Combine Excel Spreadsheets

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel workbook with many tabs.
Each tab has the same set of headers as all others.
I want to combine all of the data from each tab into one data frame (without repeating the headers for each tab).

So far, I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
df = xl.parse()
```

Can use something for the parse argument that will mean "all spreadsheets"?
Or is this the wrong approach?

Thanks in advance!

Update: I tried:

```
a=xl.sheet_names
b = pd.DataFrame()
for i in a:
    b.append(xl.parse(i))
b
```

But it's not "working".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is one way to do it -- load all sheets into a dictionary of dataframes and then concatenate all the values in the dictionary into one dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
```

Set sheetname to None in order to load all sheets into a dict of dataframes
and ignore index to avoid overlapping values later (see comment by @bunji)

```
df = pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=None)
```

Then concatenate all dataframes

```
cdf = pd.concat(df.values())

print(cdf)
```

Comment: This is a very good answer.  Just a quick addition though: the indexes of your dataframes will probably have overlapping values so you should ignore the indexes when doing the concatenation `cdf = pd.concat(df.values(), ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: `TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument sheetname` in Python 3.71 and pandas 1.0.5

Comment: Looks like the parameter is `sheet_name` and not `sheetname`.

Comment: `ignore_index=True` is not (anymore) a parameter of `pd.read_excel`, it should rather be `index_col=None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd  

f = 'file.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None, ignore_index=True) 
df2 = pd.concat(df, sort=True)

df2.to_excel('merged.xlsx', 
             engine='xlsxwriter', 
             sheet_name=Merged,
             header = True,
             index=False)
```