# Using Pandas, how can I combine multiple worksheets based on one column in the "master sheet"?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got 9 different tabs in an Excel sheet, each with different information. On Tab 1 (considered "master tab"), I have the most complete data set, but I need to add one column of information from Tabs 2-9, based on matching a specific column in MasterTab.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.ExcelFile('AprilTest.xlsx')
df1 = df.parse('MasterTab')
df2 = df.parse('Tab2')


check=pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ClientID', how='left')
```

MasterTab looks like this:

```
ClientID    val1    val2    val3
foo         bar     baz     12/2/16
cat         dog     pan     1/12/16
zzz         yyy     vvv     6/8/16
trick       lol     hmm     4/28/17
```

Tab2-9 MAY have the same clientIDs, they may have more, they may have fewer.

example Tab2:

```
Name   FavoriteColor   ClientID   Metric Value
Jodi   Green           foo        16
Kati   Purple          trick      29
Sam    Blue            bar        32
```

The final sheet should look like this:

```
ClientID    val1    val2    val3    Metric Value
foo         bar     baz     12/2/16  16
cat         dog     pan     1/12/16  0
zzz         yyy     vvv     6/8/16   0
trick       lol     hmm     4/28/17  29
```

I've looked at a few resources here:
[pandas Combine Excel Spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950672/pandas-combine-excel-spreadsheets)
https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_join_merge_dataframe.html

but nothing seems to be working the way I expect it to. The code I've got now just adds df2 to the bottom of MasterTab, which is not what I need. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Basically, you have to add just the 'MetricValue' column to the Master?

Comment: does it help if you add `.reset_index(drop=True)` to the end of your `df1 = df.parse` and `df2 = df.parse` lines? And are you sure 'ClientID' is spelled exactly the same in df1 and df2?

Comment: yeah @MaxPower, it's all spelled exactly the same, no spacing issues or anything.

Comment: @user3043636, that's correct, but it has to be matched. So I can't have foo bar baz 29, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
df1['Metric'] = df1.ClientID.map(df2.set_index('ClientID').MetricValue).fillna(0)
```

df1

You get

```
    ClientID    val1    val2    val3    Metric
0   foo         bar     baz     12/2/16 16.0
1   cat         dog     pan     1/12/16 0.0
2   zzz         yyy     vvv     6/8/16  0.0
3   trick       lol     hmm     4/28/17 29.0
```

Comment: What value would I change to do it for Tab3?

Comment: Which column is Tab3?

Comment: Ok given Tab3 is another dataframe, you set index of that df on the id on which you are merging(ClientID in this case) and then .MetricValue uses the column whose values you need.

Comment: Tab3 has the ClientID in Column 2 and the value I need is in Column 3. So if I understand correctly, I'd have:
df3= df.parse('Tab3')
df1['Metric'] = df1.ClientID.map(df3.set_index('ClientID').MetricValue).fillna(1)

Comment: Yeah and fillna(0) replaces NANs with 0 so it would be that and not fillna(1), unless you want the NANs to be replaced by 1

Comment: Now what if MetricValue actually has a space in it? It won't accept Metric_Value or Metric Value. Do I have to change the column name in my spreadsheet?

Comment: No need to change name in spreadsheet, you need to change to df3.set_index('ClientID').Metric_Value

Comment: I have this: 

df1['Metric'] = df1.ClientID.map(df2.set_index('ClientID').Metric_Value).fillna(0)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Metric_Value'

Comment: That means that your data frame df2 doesn't have a column Metric_Value. Aren't you using df3 now?

Comment: Df2 does have Metric Value. All of the tabs do, actually. But specifically in Excel the column is called Metric Value, with the space.

Comment: Then use set_index('ClientID')['Metric Value']