# How can I export my calculation process of multiple dataframes in different shapes to one sheet in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I would like to export multiple dataframes in different shapes to only one Excel sheet in order to illustrate my entire calculation process to the final result but I am not sure how to do so. The number of rows in the dataframes could be different depending on the inputs so I cannot specify the exact Excel cell range to export. Or can I consolidate them but not appending them to the end of another df as the columns are very different across. Can anyone please help? Many thanks!!

Below please find the extract of all my calculation steps:

print(df1)

```
   Qualifier      Curve Tenor  Bucket      RiskType  AmountUSD
0        AUD    Libor3m    1m     1.0  Risk_IRCurve    2000000
1        AUD    Libor3m    2y     1.0  Risk_IRCurve   -2000000
2        AUD    Libor3m    6m     1.0  Risk_IRCurve    3000000
3        CHF    Libor6m   15y     1.0  Risk_IRCurve   -4000000
4        CHF    Libor6m   20y     1.0  Risk_IRCurve   10000000
5        CHF    Libor6m   30y     1.0  Risk_IRCurve   12000000
6        CNY    Libor1m    3m     3.0  Risk_IRCurve    -500000
```

print(df2)

```
  Qualifier                   Currency Risk Group  Delta Concentration threshold (USD/bp)   CR
0       AUD  Regular volatility, less well-traded                                41000000  1.0
1       CHF  Regular volatility, less well-traded                                41000000  1.0
2       CNY                       High volatility                                31000000  1.0
3       EUR       Regular volatility, well-traded                               220000000  1.0
4       JPY                        Low volatility                                99000000  1.0
5       MXN                       High volatility                                31000000  1.0
6       USD       Regular volatility, well-traded                               220000000  1.0
```

print(df3)

```
  Bucket            Kb
0    AUD  3.405710e+08
1    CHF  1.208374e+09
2    CNY  1.651178e+08
3    EUR  3.732483e+09
4    JPY  1.927114e+09
5    MXN  1.526896e+09
6    USD  4.241642e+08
```

I have tried the following code but it is dumb. Does anyone have better idea to do this?

```
tt = df1.shape[0]
tt2 = df1.shape[0] + df2.shape[0]
        with pd.ExcelWriter(Results, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
            df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='IR delta',startrow=0, index=False)
            df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='IR delta', startrow=tt + 3, index=False)
            df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='IR delta', startrow=tt2 + 6, index=False)
```

Comment: I have further used your data to test the codes.  Separated the 3 to_excel() calls under 3 `with pd.ExcelWriter..` statements with specifying the same sheet_name "combine" for them.  3 sets of DataFrame data are seen but they are separated into 3 sheets named "combine", "combine1", "combine2".   Seems that the to_Excel function automatically created new sheets for different DataFrame even under append mode.  Probably need to explore some other way out.

Comment: @SeaBean Can I "combine" these dataframes into one set of data and export? But they are of entirely different shapes and have different column names

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950672/pandas-combine-excel-spreadsheets/35951010) whether it gives you some hints.  Firstly write your dataframes to different sheets and then read back using sheet_name=None and concat.  See whether it work.

Comment: @SeaBean But the dataframes I want to export have different headers and different shapes. How can I keep the headers of each dataframe and not merge them together?

Comment: @SeaBean Please see my updated codes. Do you have better idea than this? Many thanks!

Comment: That sounds great!  I tested it alright to combine in one sheet!  I think this is the best that we can do.  As I have informed you earlier that even if I split the codes to 3 `with ...` statements, pandas only creates different sheets for different dataframes rather than combine them into one.  With this codes of specifying startrow such that they won't overlap, it seems relaxes the checking of pandas not to automatically create new sheets for different dataframes.   Although not perfect, I think this is already sufficiently good codes.  So I would recommend using this.